# How to configure partials and layouts for Handlebars in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, sails.js

I run [Sails `0.9.7`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/tree/717d85b96533c5705a061fd63bfd08061b3d89a6) and have installed [Handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) which is supported by [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js) and therefore is [supported by Sails](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/bin/boilerplates/config/views.js#L18)

I can serve pages from `.handlebars` files, it works just fine.
I can't figure where, in Sails workflow, and in a *Sails way*, I should register partials, helpers etc... I'm more looking for best practices than just a *working solution* but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I've tried making views/partials/ and putting them there, I've tried in views/ and in views/<controller>/ and even views/<controller>/partials/ :-(

Comment: I don't think Sails' going to pick these up automatically. The comments are clear `Layout support is only implemented for the ejs view engine! For most other engines, it is not necessary, since they implement partials/layouts themselves` it just doesn't say how/where it should be done.

Comment: I don't know if I'm ready to give up on it. Underneath, it's just express, right? I've used other template engines with Express after a little tweaking. Here's what I'm trying to do with Sails: http://www.bearfruit.org/2013/08/22/a-better-template-engine-for-express-apps/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm running v0.10 beta but this shouldn't affect how I got it working below:

1. Engine should be **handlebars** as expected
2. Routes need to explicitly define controller and action. Setting view won't work. (Unless there's a way I couldn't figure out of setting the partials in the routes file)
3. Controller needs partials defined as paths relative to the view.

**config/views.js**

```
module.exports.views = {
  engine      : 'handlebars',
  layout      : false
};
```

**config/routes.js**

```
'/': {
  controller: 'site',
  action: 'index'
},
```

**SiteController.js**

```
module.exports = {
  // Render Index View
  index: function(req, res) {
    res.view({
      partials: {
        head: 'partials/head',
        tail: '../partials/tail',
      },
    });
  }
};
```

**views/site/index.handlebars**

```
{{> head}}
<h3>SITE INDEX</h3>
```

**views/site/partials/head.handlebars**

```
<h1>HEAD</h1>
{{> tail}}
```

**views/partials/tail.handlebars**

```
<h2>HEAD TAIL</h2>
```

## OUTPUT

```
<h1>HEAD</h1>
<h2>HEAD TAIL</h2>
<h3>SITE INDEX</h3>
```

Comment: Yes, so it's basically the same as @christopher-pappas answer or did I misunderstood something ? Thanks for your detailed answer.

Comment: His answer is incomplete - You have to explicitly set the controller and action in the route definition - it's the only way I could get it to work - but i've since moved on to nunjucks for template inheritance

Comment: Ok, I guess it's as far as I can go with raw sails, then I would need to write some sort of policie or plugin to only declare a partials folder, and have the `partials` option be filled automatically with all the partials I have put in my partials folder. Thanks for your complete answer.

Comment: @JeremieParker I got around this issue by storing all my partials as an object literal in config/views.js, and then using underscore to clone that object whenever I render a new view: `res.view({ partials: _.clone(sails.config.views.partials) });` Still no luck in figuring out how to integrate helpers, so if anyone knows that, please share.

Comment: I use nunjucks also. what would I need to change to get nunjucks to work?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using the answers given above, but I seem to have made partials work with sails 0.9.8 with no hacks.

Here's what I have.

Config/views.js =>
engine: "handlebars"

views/home/index.handlebars => main file using the partial.

views/home/partials/partial.handlebars => partial being used.

Then as long as you use something like this, it works perfectly.
    res.view({
        partials: { 
          partial: 'partials/partial',
          footer: 'partials/footer'
        }
    })

The paths are relative to the template file called by default. So if you want different partials per controller you use partials/
and if you want global partials for all templates you use ../partials/

Obviously this is completely unto you as you need to specify every partial manually in the controller anyway.

Comment: Yes, I've figured that out too, but I was more looking for a way to call partials from the template itself, `{{> partial }}`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: so following the above - im passing `{partials: {header: 'partials/header'}}` and calling the partial `{{> header}}`.  I'm given the following error message:  `verbose: Running res.view([object Object]) method...  
error: Error rendering view at ::  
error: Using layout located at ::  
error: Server Error (500)  
error: Error: The partial header could not be found`

Comment: Where is partial actually saved? The folder partials should be in the same place as the template, and it should have a file inside called header.handlebars does that work?

Comment: And Jeremy, I guess you want a way to be able to import partials from within the template, so you can use {{> path to partial}}
I would love a solution like that but Handlebars seems to be coded in a way that it needs all partials to be registered, sadly.

Comment: there's a module called mmm on npm that is the same as mustache, and automatically finds partials by pathname.
I've used it with express before. It doesn't have the extra handlebar features, but its usually good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:  This was fairly easy to implement via the express3-handlebars module while changing none of the default Sails functionality with the exception of asking you to move your layout file into `views/layouts`.  I've opened up a pull-request here (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/1075) if you would like to check it out.

---

After a bit of digging in the sails source-code, it's fairly easy to bring in partials when you render your view.

When you call `res.view` in your controller actions, just pass in a partials object as part of your "locals" which contains a list of partials you'd like rendered.

```
  // LoginController.js
  new: function (req, res) {
    res.view({
        partials: { 
          header: '../partials/header',
          footer: '../partials/footer'
        }
    })
  }

  // new.handlebars
  {{> header}}
      <b>Main content</b>
  {{> footer}}
```

Helpers can be registered in a similar way, by attaching a key named `helpers` and passing in the functionality.

It would be nice if there was a more formalized way to do this in the Sails core, but for now this should suffice for those who want to use handlebars instead of ejs while preserving some semblance of layouts.

Comment: To be clear, if your pull request gets merged, I'll be happy to accept your answer, otherwise, hacking sails core is kind of a no-go right now considering we'd like to be able to update Sails (to leverage coming functionalities such as transaction) without having to patch every time. In the mean time I've upvoted your answer since its actually close to what I'm looking for but not as reusable as I would like it to be.

Comment: Agreed.  The more comfortable I get with sails the more I'm hacking the core to achieve what I need.  Its unfortunate, but then again the framework is new.  Just trying to point a way ;)

Comment: This did not work for me. Using absolute paths and relative paths failed.

Comment: Where exactly should the partials folder live? Is the .. relative to the parent view? Should it live in views/partials?

Comment: It should live in views/partials.  But keep in mind that sails 0.10 is significantly different and so I would avoid the above; I tried refactoring it but it seems like sails.js decided to leave a hard .ejs dependency in favor of a plugin-like architecture (that has yet to be written / documented)

Comment: Yeah I've mostly given up on this. I figured if I need partials - I can register them using hbs.registerPartial(); but its a single page app that doesn't need server side rendering aside from the wrapping head and body markup. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 2):

FYI,

If you're using Sails 0.10 or above, I have published an NPM package to generate default handlebars views at https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails-generate-views-handlebars

There is also a proposed PR for sails-generate-backend in order to properly support layouts and partials for handlebar when using ‘sails generate –template==handlebars’ with no additional code and automatic discovery of partials based on a path (aka. views/partial/**)

See: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-backend/pull/9

Answer (score 1):

I'm running out of time but I'm getting close to an answer, I think. I'll update this reply when I get more details, but if you want to poke at it, check out line 501 in the included consolidate.js file. View on github here: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/configuration/consolidate.js#L501

It looks like for Handlebars there is a for loop that registers partials from options.partials.

That is not exactly a very satisfying solution, but if you push your partials on to that options object then maybe it will pull from that.

The big question I have next is, what is the options object, and where does it get set at?

Comment: The `options` object is the read from the `locals` variable passed in from your view controller.  See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring handlebars template in sails js , follow below steps:

1) install handlebars in your application's node_modules folder:

> npm install handlebars

2) change your config/views.js

```
engine:   'handlebars',
layout:   'layouts/layout', // layouts is subfolder of view folder in sails app and layout is a handlebars inside layouts folder.
partials: 'partials'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sails supports handlebars and its (multiple-layout, partials) natively, if we use .handlebars extensions for our files instead of .hbs.

So to use handlebars in Sails instead of EJS, it advised to use **consolidate**(Its a template engine consolation library). Handlebars works good with **SailsJs + consolidate**.

You need to install consolidate.

```
npm install consolidate --save
```

And then you just have to update the **config/views.js** file with the following content.

```
module.exports.views = {

engine: {
    ext: 'handlebars',
    fn: require("consolidate").handlebars
  },

layout: 'layouts/layout',

partials: 'partials/'

};
```

Update all your .ebs files to .handlebar files and update the code inside it.

Everything will work fine.

There is a **view-generator**, for the later purpose which will generate default views for Sails(It will make a default directory structure with default files in it).

You can find it in the github repository.(https://github.com/bhaskarmelkani/sails-generate-views-hbs)

It is similar to the one officially launched by SailsJs for jade called *balderdashy/sails-generate-views-jade*.