# handlebars layouts and partials in a sails.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, sails.js

I'm developing a web application with sails.js v0.10 and I'm using handlebars templates, I want to use layouts and partials. I figured out that sails.js uses express3-handlebars to provide handlebars layouts and partials. But I can't use both at the same time.

My config/views.js file is:

```
    ...
    engine: 'handlebars',
    layout: 'layouts/main.handlebars'
    ...
```

This works perfectly, the layout is loaded. The problem is when I'm try to use partials, I get an error saying that the partial was not found.

```
    //UserController.js
    ...
    index: function(req, res) {
        res.view({partials: {userlist: 'partials/userlist'}});
    ...
```

This only works when I change the value of the config/views.js layout property to false. But when I do that I can't use layouts anymore.

is it a bug in sails.js? or, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to configure partials and layouts for Handlebars in Sails.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810671/how-to-configure-partials-and-layouts-for-handlebars-in-sails-js)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since the linked one is specific to Sails v0.9. The behavior the user explains does not happen in that version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug. It is actually by design.

In Express 3, built-in support for layouts/partials was deprecated. Instead, developers are expected to rely on the view engines themselves to implement this features. (See https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/494 for more info on that.)

Since adopting Express 3, Sails has chosen to support the legacy layouts feature for convenience, backwards compatibility with Express 2.x and Sails 0.8.x apps, and in particular, familiarity for new community members coming from other MVC frameworks. As a result, layouts have only been tested with the default view engine (ejs).

If layouts aren’t your thing, or (for now) if you’re using a server-side view engine other than ejs, (e.g. Jade, handlebars, haml, dust) you’ll want to set layout:false in sails.config.views, then rely on your view engine’s custom layout/partial support.