# Sails - handlebars can't locate partials

Tags: coffeescript, sails.js, handlebars.js

I recently updated my Sails.js to v0.10.4 and I can't get handlebars partials to work (Haven't tried this on older versions). I have 3 partials in my index.handlebars {{> head }}, {{> body }} and {{> footer }} . The error it gives me is :

```
{
  "message": "The partial head could not be found",
  "name": "Error"
}
```

My *router* looks like this:

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    controller: 'home'
    action: 'index'
    view: 'index'
  }
}
```

and my *HomeController*:

```
module.exports = {

  index: (req, res) ->
    res.view {
      partials: {
        head: 'login/head'
        body: 'login/body'
        footer: 'login/footer'
    }}
}
```

the head.handlebars, body.handlebars and footer.handlebars are located in *views/login/*

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your configs are correct:

config/views.js

```
module.exports.views = {
  engine      : 'handlebars',
  layout      : false
};
```

Also, I don't think setting the `view` will work. (Unless there's a way I couldn't figure out of setting the partials in the routes file).

```
  '/': {
    controller: 'home',
    action: 'index'
  }
```

Finally, I believe controller needs partials defined as paths relative to the view.

Comment: I already tried this. It feels like sails just ignores the partials for handlebars.

Comment: This suggests otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19810671/how-to-configure-partials-and-layouts-for-handlebars-in-sails-js